# regression test dealing with hard coded path

Tags: python, linux, unit-testing, regression

I need to extend a python code which has plenty of hard coded path
In order not to mess everything, I want to create unit-tests for the code before my modifications: it will serve as non-regression tests with my new code (that will not have hard-coded paths)

But because of hard coded system path, I shall run my test inside a chroot tree (I don't want to pollute my system dir)
My problem is that I want to set up the chroot only for test, and this can be done with os.chroot only with root privileges (and I don't want to run the test scripts as root)

In fact, I just need a fake tree diretory so that when the code that `open('/etc/resolv.conf)` retrieves a fake resolv.conf and not my system one

I obviously don't want to replace myself the hard coded path in the code because it would not be *real* regression test

Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

Thanks

Note that all the path accessed are readable with a user accout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your test set-up you could override the built-in `open` in the module that you are testing with your own version that reads from your "fake" directory structure:

```
import mymod
import os.path

def chroot_open(filename,*args):
    filename = os.path.join("/home/you/fakeroot",filename)
    return open(filename,*args)

mymod.open = chroot_open
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a helper application that is setuid root to run the chroot; that would avoid the need to run the tests as root. Of course, that would probably still open up a local root exploit, so should only be done with appropriate precautions (e.g. in a VM image).

At any rate, any solution with chroot is inherently platform-dependent, so it's rather awkward. I actually like the idea of Dave Webb (override `open`) better, I must admit...